# In sql server are user define stored procedures still valid after rename database

Tags: sql-server

For example, I have a self defined stored procedure called What_DB_is_this under database called test. Then I rename database test to test_dev.

IN SSMS, I still can call What_DB_is_this by exec [test_dev].[dbo].What_DB_is_this in query. But if I right click on the sp, choose "script sp as" -> "create to" -> "New Query Editor Window", I encounter error: failed to retrieve data for this request can't open database "test".
Seems it is trying to connect to old db, how can i fix this prolem?

Comment: Have you refreshed the object explorer? Sounds like you haven't and so it still thinks th database is called `test`.

Comment: I refreshed, but still hit the same error.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, I'm afraid, @Shan . Close SSMS and reconnect, dose it still error then? But I would suspect that you still have not refreshed the object explorer

Comment: I tried to replicate your problem, but I cannot; after I refreshed the object explorer I could get the definition of the object. [No repro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEan7.gif). *(Excuse the tiny screen, I restored the size of my VM to that the image size wouldn't be huge.)*

Comment: I stopped the instance then restart,  fixed. Do I really have to restart the instance?? Or it is a bug SQL Server.

Comment: No, as I showed. You didn't refresh the object explorer. There is no bug; as I demonstrated.

Comment: @Larnu Yes I suspect there is something wrong with the connection or SSMS.  Thank you. Appreciated your reply very much

Comment: Now is a good time to develop and implement a disaster recovery plan. That goes along with some way putting your entire schema into source control (even if just a backup - better than nothing). If you need source code, you should pull that from your source control system, not just grab whatever is currently in some database.